# issue working with react-testing-library with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

Trying to write my first test with react-testing-library, but it seems like it would not grab the correct material-ui element.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lx5nl1839z

I get the error message saying the event was never fired.

> Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.

When I change the `button` to a regular button instead of Button from material ui, then it works.

Here is my test

```
test('calls with user email and password', () => {
  const login = jest.fn();
  const error = null as any;

  const { getByLabelText, getByText } = render(
    <LoginForm login={login} error={error} />
  );

  const email = getByLabelText('Email');
  const password = getByLabelText('Password');
  (email as any).value = 'leoq91@gmail.com';
  (password as any).value = 'password';
  fireEvent.click(getByText('Login'));


  expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      email: 'leoq91@gmail.com',
      password: 'password',
  });
});
```

Here is my component:

```
export const LoginForm: FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({ login, error }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  return (
    <Paper style={{ width: '400px', padding: '30px', margin: '0 auto' }}>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          return login({ email, password });
        }}
      >
        <TextField
          id="email"
          label="Email"
          onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          fullWidth
          variant="outlined"
          error={Boolean(getEmailError(email))}
          helperText={getEmailError(email)}
        />
        <TextField
          id="password"
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}
          onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          fullWidth
          variant="outlined"
        />
        <LoginError error={error} />
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
          // disabled={isDisabled(email, password)}
          style={{
            margin: '20px 0px',
          }}
        >
          Login
        </Button>
      </form>
      <Divider />
      <Typography style={{ margin: '10px auto' }}>Forgot password?</Typography>
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

Comment: Did you inspect what `getByLabelText` actually returned? Could you clean up your code so that one could simply past it into a codesandbox and inspect what's being rendered?

Comment: @epsilon https://codesandbox.io/s/lx5nl1839z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, codesandbox is not reliable...

> codesandbox is somehow running the tests in the browser and not in jsdom.

Here is the issue: 
https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/issues/234

Gist of it is because it is clicking the `submit` span, not the button. It should have bubbled up, but it isn't.

Here is a working example with my local server with Typescript.

```
test('calls with user email and password', () => {
    const login = jest.fn();

    const { getByLabelText, container } = render(
      <LoginForm login={login} error={null} />
    );

    const emailNode = getByLabelText('Email');
    const passwordNode = getByLabelText('Password');

    if (
      emailNode instanceof HTMLInputElement &&
      passwordNode instanceof HTMLInputElement
    ) {
      fireEvent.change(emailNode, { target: { value: 'leoq91@gmail.com' } });
      fireEvent.change(passwordNode, { target: { value: 'password' } });
      const form = container.querySelector('form') as HTMLFormElement;
      form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));
      expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        email: emailNode.value,
        password: passwordNode.value,
      });
    } else {
      expect(false);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TextFields are not controlled. You should pass the actual value and set the actual value in the change event.
You fire submit twice currently in your tests.

Running the tests with those fixes has the correct console output but for some reason codesandbox ignores the jest matcher. I don't know what's going on there but with the above fixes the gist of it works.

Comment: it is a form, it doesn't necessarily need to be tracked with the state.

Comment: If you call your `login  callback with state values of your Login component then you  have to save the values from the inputs into the state. You do this by using controlled inputs. Otherwise your test will never pass regardless of the use input components.

Comment: https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/issues/234 I submitted the request, as you can see this is a jsdom issue. @epsilon

Comment: My test did pass without using a controlled input just as expected. The form does not need to have a controlled input.

Comment: No it doesn't but you `login` callback was useless without a controlled component. How do you think the state in your `Login` component would be set otherwise?

Comment: oh boy, did you even see kentDodd's comment? The library creator's comment... I dont know why would you downvote something even the lib creator already said it was a bug. The problem is with jsdom, it is not bubbling up the event as it suppose to. Since Button has Span inside of it...

Comment: I understand that this is a jsdom bug. I was specifically targeting about your test setup. You spied on a callback that was using values from the `Login` component state but those values were never used in your component anyway. For the record the original answer did not have change handlers in the TextField. They were added after my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been figthing over this for a while and finally got something to put the data-testid on the input and not the div around it that composed the TextField in material-ui.

You should set the `data-testid` in the inputProps like this:

```
<TextField
     type="password"
     variant="outlined"
     required
     value={password}
     onChange={onChangePassword}
     inputProps={{
         'data-testid': 'testPassword'
     }}
 />
```

And then you can access it in your test like that and simulate a new user input:

```
const passwordInput = getByTestId('testPassword');
fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: VALID_PASSWORD } });
```

Answer (score -1):

I saw many people having issues with material-ui. My guess is that `Button` is trying to do some fancy thing and breaks the normal HTML event flow.

My advice is to use [jest.mock()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) and mock `Button` to render a `button` instead.